# Looking for a MAP to SLD converter

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, convert, sld

Does anyone know where I can find the converter from .map to .sld?

I have a big mapfile of styles for OSM and I have the styles mapnik.xml for OSM but I use Geoserver for my work. Or does anyone have some sld styles of OSM for PostGIS layers planet_osm_point and planet_osm_polygon? (I already have the style for planet_osm_line.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a converter being developed by Dave Winslow at https://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools that may be able to do what you want. If you just want SLD to style OSM then you could look at https://github.com/darrell/openstreetmap-sld

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map file to create a MapServer WMS, then you can perform a GetStyles request which will generate an SLD file.  For example looking at the BGS 625k Geology WMS:

- [GetCapabilities](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&)

The response shows that GetStyles is supported:

```
<ms:GetStyles>
    <Format>text/xml</Format>
    <DCPType>
        <HTTP>
            <Get>
                <OnlineResource 
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                    xlink:href="http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?language=eng&"/>
            </Get>
            <Post>
                <OnlineResource 
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                    xlink:href="http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?language=eng&"/>
            </Post>
        </HTTP>
    </DCPType>
</ms:GetStyles>
```

and gives us us the list of layer names including **GBR_BGS_625k_BLT**, to which we can apply the request, like:

- [GetStyles](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?service=WMS&request=GetStyles&layers=GBR_BGS_625k_BLT&version=1.3.0&)

Comment: Interesting idea. will need check this way. Thanx)