# Tools to help migration from Mapserver to QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, wms, mapserver, migration, qgs

I'm going to migrate a Mapserver WMS server to QGIS Server.

I'd like to know if there are some tools or plugins that convert Mapserver mapfile (.map) to QGIS project file (.qgs). WMS responses (GetCapabilities, GetStyles...) to QGIS project file would be also be a correct solution.

Ideally it would take care of :

- WMS server metadata
- layer's name
- layer's title
- layer's style
- layer's HTML template
- layer's minscale/maxscale view
- layer's groups
- layer's metadata
- ....

Comment: Possible duplicate question. Look at the answer to this question where someone was "Looking for a MAP to SLD converter": http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11715/looking-for-a-map-to-sld-converter

Comment: This is a good start but styles are only a part of layers definition. I'm updating my question to list information needed.

Comment: MapServer has more functionality that QGIS Server, so you might have problems trying to migrate all your MapServer settings to QGIS Server